# Updating a CSS property during a transtion, smooth in all browsers but very buggy in Safari?

Tags: javascript, css, safari

Here's an example of what I mean, this pen is created to isolate the bug i'm finding, and I'm after any solutions to make it work in Safari in the same way you're seeing in Chrome, Firefox or Edge.

https://codepen.io/kylewetton/pen/rNOOXBg

*(Please try this pen in both Safari and Chrome/Firefox/Edge to see the difference)*

**Click and drag around the window, and the ball will follow your cursor.**

```
...
document.addEventListener('mousemove', ev => {
    let x = ev.clientX;
    let y = ev.clientY;
    active && move(x, y);
});

function move(x, y) {
    ball.style.left = `${x - 25}px`;
    ball.style.top = `${y - 25}px`;
};
```

This is where the problem comes in. There is a *transition* CSS property on the ball that allows it to smoothly glide toward the cursor, **even though the *top* and *left* are continuously being updated.** This seems to be calculated correctly in all browsers, but Safari can't handle it.

```
#ball {
  ....
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

Does anybody have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Try using also property   -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out in your #ball CSS

Comment: Thanks, however that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Safari is the new Internet Explorer